# TSQL extract part of string with regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

i would make a script that iterate over the records of a table with a cursor
and extract from a column value formatted like that `"yyy://xx/bb/147011"`
only the final number `147011`and to put this value in a variable.
It's possible to do something like that?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the below query.

```
SELECT RIGHT(RTRIM('yyy://xx/bb/147011'), 
CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE('/' + RTRIM('yyy://xx/bb/147011'))) - 1) AS LastWord
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but why it's needed to RTRIM the string?

Comment: @Giu It has not any major impact.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cursor for this.  You can just use a query.  The following gets everything after the last `/`:

```
select right(str, charindex('/', reverse(str)) - 1 )
from (values ('yyy://xx/bb/147011')) v(str)
```

It does not specifically check if it is a number, but that can be added as well.

Answer (score 1):

If numeric value has exact position defined with sample data, then you can do :

```
SELECT t.*, SUBSTRING(t.col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t.col), LEN(t.col))
FROM table t;
```